# about newline in Mathematica.SE

Tags: discussion, markdown

> This is copy from cell <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

(*added in SE, no newline*)sampleList1 = {"compute", "Tes", ".", ".a", ".m", "a", "z", "T", ".T",
    "wha", "{"};

> Add indent by four/eight spaces

```
sampleList1 = {"compute", "Tes", ".", ".a", ".m", "a", "z", "T", ".T",
(here newline)"wha", "{"};
```

> Delete the newline by <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

```
sampleList1 = {"compute", "Tes", ".", ".a", ".m", "a", "z", "T", ".T", "wha", "{"};
```

My question is: Are there some reasons for this newline?

One guess is that the page width of edit window is not the same to that of preview window at least in my current Explorer Chrome.

[image]
[image]
[image]

At present I wish it will not generate the newline in that place but generate where the page width of preview window is not sufficed.
[image]

Comment: Well, this is primarily because the frontend copies code with arbitrary line breaks and indentation and what you see in your notebook is not what is copied (or I've never been able to figure out a pattern for it). If you use any decent text editor to write your code or write it inside code cells in the notebook, you shouldn't run into this issue.

Comment: @rm-rf ah, so it is. Copy directly from Code style cell seems like `copy as plaintext`. And I find copy from Input cell will preserve spaces in codes, but encounter the newline problem. 
f[space in SE]@@[space in SE]list except f@list. I'm trying use this to copy from input cell. First@FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[CellExpression,"InputText"], when I use "PlainText", then no newline problem, but also without spaces between codes.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Re: preserve spaces in code — input cells will insert  additional spaces to code (i.e., not added by the user) and will sometimes refuse to add additional spaces/tabs where you want it to. So it's not necessarily "preserving" it, because I don't know what's there underneath the hood to begin with. Code cells, on the other hand, will preserve everything in it — the catch is that you'll have to enter spaces around operators yourself.

Comment: You can determine the column at which the Front End wraps lines in copied test with this system option: `ExportTypesetOptions -> {"PageWidth" -> 90}` -- I use 90 based on [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/465/code-box-line-width-survey).  Also see [this question on Main.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17540/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard nice, it works.